# Replacing integers with variables in SQL commands in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pyqt

So currently my code is this which works

```
result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM PastOrders WHERE CustomerID="1";')
```

But as others use my programme the customer will change so how do I replace 1 with a variable like this..

```
cat = str(1)    
result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM PastOrders WHERE CustomerID=cat;')
```

However, this doesn't work so any help thanks

Comment: The [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) covers this for you; look for *placeholders* and *parameters*. Do not use string interpolation, as that would open you up to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: For this specific query, use one placeholder (`?`): `result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM PastOrders WHERE CustomerID=?;', (cat,))`, there `cat` is the customer ID. You do not need to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered breaking the SQL statement.

```
cat = '\"+'str(1)+'\"';
result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM PastOrders WHERE CustomerID='+cat+';)'
```

Comment: ***NO***, you should ***NEVER*** use string formatting to interpolate untrusted data into a SQL command!

Comment: See the [OWASP SQL Injection overview](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) for why this is a **really bad idea**.

Comment: He should add some security measures. Converting html special characters and SQL keywords.

Comment: Yes, and the first security measure is to *use SQL parameters and not use string formatting*.

Comment: From the `sqlite3` documentation: *Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method.*. SQL parameters take care of proper escaping of values for you.

Comment: How to do that, I don't think I've ever heard of it.